# Mirror X topology problem

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode, mirror

i've run into a problem here.

When i want to use mirror X topology option in edit mode - my mesh gets distorted in the middle and cannot find any options to fix that.

[image: Fine before starting to edit with mirror X topology enabled]

[image: The problem appears when starting to edit topology]

BLEND: [image]

Comment: Please upload a .blend file to be able to help you

Comment: Is your model directly over the x-axis? It appears to me that your model is shifted slightly in the **-x** direction.

Comment: @Tak Added Blend file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model is not constructed with x-mirror perfectly and the armature is not placed in the exact middle of your mesh as shown below:

[image]